# Checkbox set to yes/no depending on date in another field in an Access Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a field in MS Access named "Paus until" and a yes/no field named "Active". I want the users to be able to set a date in the future and automatically uncheck the active-box. When the date is equal to today or in the past the checkbox status should turn back to checked.

The code I wrote works in a weird way. When there is a date set in the future the user is unable to check the box, but nothing happens automatically. Vice versa if the date is in the past the user is unable to uncheck the box but nothing happens automatically. I have used the AfterUpdate function.

```
Private Sub yesnobox_AfterUpdate()
    Dim targetDatum As Date
    Dim TodayDatum As Date

    targetDatum = [Paus_until]

    TodayDatum = Date()

    If targetDatum >= TodayDatum Then
        Me.[Active] = True
    Else
        Me.[Active] = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm writing this from memory and might have misprinted something small, but what am I missing here?
I see many answered questions to yes/no-checkboxes but they are too involved and specific for me to extrapolate a solution from.

Comment: Sounds like this check field is not needed in table. Just calculate this check value when needed for display on report.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your code in two parts, if i understand correct the event should take place after updating the date field.

So add this code after the date field is updated...

```
Private Sub txtPauseUntil_AfterUpdate()

    If IsDate(Me.txtPauseUntil) Then
        '
        Me.Active = IsActive(Me.txtPauseUntil)
        '
    End If

End Sub
```

This you can alter based on your needs.

```
Public Function IsActive(ByVal dtTarget As Date)

    If dtTarget >= Date Then
       IsActive = True
    Else
       IsActive = False
    End If
    
End Function
```

Good luck.

Comment: Or `IsActive = dtTarget >= Date`.